# websocat server with timestamp

Tags: socket

I am running `websocat` (https://github.com/vi/websocat/) on macOS in server mode for debugging purposes.

I would like to display a timestamp on every incoming message.

However: I am struggling with parameter syntax: how would add that overlay parameter when running in **server** mode.

My current command line looks like this `websocat -s <myip>:<myport>`, everything works as expected but I cannot add the timestamp overlay to it

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
websocat - log:timestamp:"wss://echo.websocket.events"
```

Output

> websocat: It is recommended to either set --binary or --text explicitly
>
> READ 59 "1671395858.65176 echo.websocket.events sponsored by Lob.com"
>
> 1671395858.65176 echo.websocket.events sponsored by Lob.com

The result is not exactly timestamp. The time is in seconds (nanosecond precision) (Use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert back to timestamp)

Also you can try **--timestamp-monotonic** flag for monotonicity.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Is “1671395858.65176” a timestamp? … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).